# The StackExchange™ AttentionCathalizer TwitteringFeedotron™ should check a question's status before twitteriring it

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, deleted-questions, stack-exchange-button

Case in point:

> Okami questions... [ur.ly/BR5A](http://ur.ly/BR5A) #wii
>
> [<sub>StackGaming</sub>](http://twitter.com/#!/StackGaming/status/29673767244402688)

The question author got his question deleted a few minutes after he posted it. Still, it was the only question asked in this period and hence got <s>twittereredeted</s> shared.

(Does the same happen with other question statuses such as "locked" or "closed"?)

Comment: This is the greatest question title of all time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fix for this will go out next build.

> Does the same happen with other question statuses such as "locked" or "closed"?

Closed questions are also excluded, locked questions can be tweeted - locked isn't necessarily a *bad* question, so these are not excluded.

Typically the "hotness" algorithm in place prevents any of these from showing up, but I just added a not deleted/not closed check just before the tweet goes out to ensure we don't tweet any of these questions in the future.

Some additional info on the feed - since I've seen a few questions here and there: a question need not be posted between tweets to be a tweeted question, though age does play a factor.  So it's *more likely* to be tweeted if that's the case, but not a requirement - we'll go down and find another "hot" question if need be.

Comment: You can't vote on a locked question, so why tweet it?